# How do I add xx seconds, minutes, or hours to a DateTime structure?

Tags: datetime, erlang

I'd like to add a certain period of time to an existing `DateTime` value (in `{{Y,M,D},{H,m,s}}` format), but don't see a function (such as in the `Calendar` module) that allows me to manipulate a `DateTime` value directly.

How can I add (for example) 10 seconds, 10 minutes, or 10 hours to such a value?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Calendar` module to convert the `DateTime` to seconds, which makes it easier to add the desired seconds, minutes, hours, etc.

For example, to add 10 seconds:

```
Date = {{2018,8,14},{13,10,25}}.
DateInSeconds = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(Date).  % 63701471425
NewDateInSeconds = DateInSeconds + 10.                         % 63701471435
calendar:gregorian_seconds_to_datetime(NewDateInSeconds).      % {{2018,8,14},{13,10,35}}
```

For 10 minutes or 10 hours, just perform a little math:

```
Date = {{2018,8,14},{13,10,25}}.
DateInSeconds = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(Date).  % 63701471425
NewDateInSeconds = DateInSeconds + (10 * 60 * 60).             % 63701507425 (10 hours)
calendar:gregorian_seconds_to_datetime(NewDateInSeconds).      % {{2018,8,14},{23,10,25}}
```

To make life easier, you could even create a function for this, to add additional time to (or subtract time from) an existing `DateTime`:

```
-type datetime() :: {{non_neg_integer(), pos_integer(), pos_integer()},
                     {non_neg_integer(), non_neg_integer(), non_neg_integer()}}.
-type timespan() :: {integer(), integer(), integer()}.

-spec add_time_to_datetime(datetime(), timespan()) -> datetime().
add_time_to_datetime(Date, {Hour, Min, Sec}) ->
    DateInSeconds = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(Date),
    NewDateInSeconds = DateInSeconds + (Hour * 60 * 60) + (Min * 60) + Sec,
    calendar:gregorian_seconds_to_datetime(NewDateInSeconds).
```

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use special time managment libs such as [qdate](https://github.com/choptastic/qdate).

Example usage, adding a year, month and minute, and removing 3 days and 5 hours.

```
NewDate = qdate:add_date({{1, 2, -3}, {-5, 1, 0}}, {{2018, 8, 16}, {11, 0, 1}}).
```

Comment: Yes, you can use qdate:add_date/2 this way or more simple funs qdate:add_seconds/2, qdate:add_minutes/2 etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to accept two datetime structures and subtract the second from the first, conversion to Gregorian seconds, performing the subtraction, and then reconversion is the most common way:

```
sub_datetime(DT1, DT2) ->
    Seconds1 = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(DT1),
    Seconds2 = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(DT2),
    Diff = Seconds1 - Seconds2,
    calendar:gregorian_seconds_to_datetime(Diff).
```

Addition is the same thing, just with the opposite operation (and of course this becomes commutative as well).

```
add_datetime(DT1, DT2) ->
    Seconds1 = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(DT1),
    Seconds2 = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(DT2),
    Sum = Seconds1 + Seconds2,
    calendar:gregorian_seconds_to_datetime(Sum).
```

This works in all situations and doesn't require deciphering anything or math other than the single operation (on your behalf, anyway). You notice, of course, the opportunity here for pulling the one unique part of these two functions out -- but that sort of DRY isn't really called for with just two functions. Meh.

If you want a "list-of-args friendly" sort of way to call the above:

```
add_time(Years, Months, Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Target) ->
    AddedTime = {{Years, Months, Days}, {Hours, Minutes, Seconds}},
    add_datetime(AddedTime, Target).
```

Comment: @GrantWinney The expectation is that you will be converting valid datetimes or offsets as partial dates, not time diffs from a fixed point -- hence the need for an `add_time/2` and separate `sub_time/2` instead of a single `add_time/2` to which you occasionally feed negative datetimes. "Gregorian", meaning what it does, account back to year 0, but not before. The [types themselves](http://erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html#type-year) define this. You can informally represent years BCE, but you would need custom functions for manipulations.

Comment: Oh, worth mentioning... Because Erlang has a universal sort order, you can use a guard to ensure that passing illegal spans cannot happen in your programs without performing any conversions (`sub_time(DT1, Dt2) when DT2 =< DT1 -> ...` and so on).

Comment: @GrantWinney That's part of a tradeoff in lib design. If you want every calculation to be checked *deeply* at runtime instead of *typechecked* before being compiled. Dates (and their conversions) seem to actually have runtime guards, whereas times are specced, but not guarded. So you can poke at the values in funny ways, but if you use Dialyzer it will complain. There is likely an historical explanation for why dates are checked but times aren't (likely having to do with the [time correction system](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/time_correction.html) which may render time types a white lie).